# Docker run without interruption

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have web applications running on Docker. When there is a new update to Production (from Gitlab), the production becomes inaccessible while the production server is pulling a new image. What can I do for it ? What are your suggestions?

Docker Swarm or Kubernetes are good choices?

Comment: This is certainly [a standard Kubernetes feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), though the mechanism isn't that difficult in the abstract: all requests to a container (Kubernetes pod) go through a load balancer (Kubernetes service), and the cluster pulls the new image and starts the new container before stopping the old one.  I've had good experiences with Kubernetes but there are a lot of complexities.

Comment: This having been said, is there something in your local setup that could be improved?  Do you have existing deployment code you can include in the question?

Comment: A basic way could be using a  blue/green strategy. For example, with HAProxy https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/traffic-routing/blue-green-deployments/. You could pair this with service discovery patterns such as using the docker resolver to find the container ips, you can look at this repo I made that goes into that topic a bit more in depth. https://github.com/bluebrown/docker-sd-and-lb-strategies